# Java executor service How to return total success and total failed record at once

Tags: process, batch-file, executorservice

I am inserting records in database using executorserive. Lets say saving 100 records by creating 5 batches each containing 20 records.

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
Collection c= new ArrayList();
 while (someloop)
 {
    c.add(mySaveMehtod());
 }
List<Future<String>> list = e.invokeAll(c);
Iterator<Future<String>> i= list.iterator();
Future<String> f=null;
 while(i.hasNext())
 {
  f= itr.next();       
 }
 Strin str = f.get();
```

While processing there might be error for some records and some records will process successfully.

Once process finishes I want to collect total successfully processed and total failed record at once.

Can anybody let me know how I can achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know if an `INSERT` of a record was successful immediately after executing the SQL, you can simply use two `AtomicInteger`s. You declare them and set to `0` before running batch insert jobs, and increment them in these jobs. Operations on `AtomicInteger`s are thread safe, so you don't need to worry about synchronization. For example:

```
public static void main() {
    AtomicInteger nSuccess = new AtomicInteger(0);
    AtomicInteger nFailed = new AtomicInteger(0);
    // add batch insert jobs
    // wait for jobs to finish
    System.out.println("succeeded: " + nSuccess.get() + " failed: " + nFailed.get());
}

class BatchInserter implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (insertRecord(i)) {
                nSuccess.getAndIncrement();
            } else {
                nFailed.getAndIncrement();
            }
        }
    }
}
```